# "How long is he working?" vs. "Since when is he working?"

Tags: present-perfect, verb-forms, present-tense

Today I asked someone about a 3rd person
*"How long is he working ?"*

He said, this is wrong question, it was suppose to be *"Since when is he working ?"*

Kindly tell me  is it wrong that i asked ?

Comment: StoneyB's answer to your actual question is spot on.  Aside:  "Is it wrong that I asked?" is a way to find out if you did the wrong thing by asking a question: _"I saw Mary yesterday.  I asked if her husband is still in prison and she burst into tears.  Is it wrong that I asked?"  ( _"Was it wrong of me to ask"_ would work also.)  You are wanting to know about the way in which you phrased the question, though, so you would say something like _"Kindly tell me; did I phrase this question correctly?"_  or _"Was the way I asked this question wrong?"

Comment: Side note : don't place a space before a question mark.

Comment: @Stephen Side note: don't place a space before a colon.

Answer (score 7):

Context, context, context!

> How long is he working?

This would be correct if your question refers to the future, from the present forward: it means "How long" or "How much longer is he expected to work?"

But if this person is working now and what you want to know is how much time he has already spent on the job, as your friend's version suggests, neither version is correct. This really wants a present perfect:

> How long has he been working?

(*Since when has he been working* is theoretically possible, but should be avoided because *since when* is usually used to express an objection to some current situation. For instance, if you walk into the office and find Joe working on a project that was previously assigned to you, you might ask "Since when has Joe been responsible for that?!")

Finally, if the person you are asking has finished and you want to know how much time he spent, you should use a simple past:

> How long did he work?

Comment: It's also possible that the friend intended to ask "When has he been working since?" (i.e. What time did he start working?), which is a subtle difference, but perfectly valid and without the objection implied by "Since when...?"

Comment: @Sabre: technically valid, perhaps, but very clumsy-sounding.

Comment: @Sabre I think most NS would say "When'd he start working?" for that -- again, something an NNS prolly wouldn't know.

Comment: As an NS, "When's he been {X}ing since?" sounds natural, and I've heard it used often... although "When'd he start {X}ing?" is probably more common, there's some nuance. For the former someone **might** decide to tell me about breaks too: "Well he got here at 9, but he took a break at noon and started again at 1"